# Java program for retrieving muliple doc files from the oracle db

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee

I want to read the docs from the database & store into to my local machine.. Can you provide any sample code snippet for this?

Regards,
Krishna

Thanks for providing suggestions... based on your suggestions I have written the code & I am completed...

Please look into my blog.. I posted the code over here...

http://muralie39.wordpress.com/java-program-to-copy-files-from-oracle-to-localhost/

Thank you guys..

Thanks,
krishna

Comment: If you could be a little more specific, and ideally tell us what you've done so far, and where your having problems, we might be able to give a decent answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Find out the table structure and datatypes used in the database
2. Then look for the tutorials on how-to-retrieve that particular oracle datatype
3. Then try to read it and convert it to something which can be saved on filesystem.

Can't help you any further with this little information.

Answer (score 0):

In order to store doc files in oracle DB, you need to use BLOB datatype.

While retrieving file from DB, you have to cast the BLOB to byte array and then 
write that byte array on disk.

I did  the same thing in C# but I think in Java also this same process will work.

Comment: Hi, i want to read the docs from the database & store into to my local machine....

Comment: @Krishna, its difficult to provide entire program. Instead follow Adeel's answer.

Comment: Hi, i am not asking about the entire program, just give me an example of some part. i have pdf & doc files in db, i want to copy to my local m/c.

Comment: Read this page. It has one example :  http://www.artima.com/forums/flat.jsp?forum=1&thread=171328

Comment: @Krishna, If you dont know/want to do program, then I think there are many IDE's available who will allow you to save those files directly into your local system. No need to write program also.

Answer (score 0):

The docs *for* the Oracle database are [available here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/indexes/documentation/index.html). Through the use of a web browser you can store them on your local machine.

I'm not sure this is quite what you are asking though. Perhaps you should edit your question to provide more information.